# Prevent scientific notation in leaflet popup - R

Tags: r, popup, leaflet, scientific-notation

I created a map in R using leaflet and the popups display the attributes in scientific notation. The values are displayed normally everywhere else except the leaflet popups. How do I change this?

Answer (score 4):

you can use either of the below option to turn off scientific notation.

```
format(xx,scientific = F)
options(scipen=999)
```

Answer (score 2):

This may solve the issue:

```
options(scipen=999)
```